# trigger.io won't launch IOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, trigger.io

Trigger.io recently stopped launching the iOS simulator when running an iOS build. Look like it might be a xcode version issue? It gets to this step and hangs

```
[INFO] Running iOS Simulator
[DEBUG] Looking for apps at /Users/kevisazombie/Projects/Web/zombiebros/beatdowncity/development/ios/simulator-*/
[DEBUG] Trying to run app /Users/kevisazombie/Projects/Web/zombiebros/beatdowncity/development/ios/simulator-ios.app/
[DEBUG] Detected XCode version 4.3 or newer
[DEBUG] Using configuration file value u'6.0' for ios.simulatorsdk
[DEBUG] Using configuration file value u'iphone' for ios.simulatorfamily
[INFO] Starting simulator
[DEBUG] Running: '/Users/kevisazombie/Projects/Web/zombiebros/beatdowncity/.template/lib/ios-sim-xc4.3' 'launch' '/Users/kevisazombie/Projects/Web/zombiebros/beatdowncity/development/ios/simulator-ios.app/' '--stderr' '/var/folders/n6/vlm01gxx2zd0qs35yqh70d8r0000gn/T/tmpL_tpLB' '--sdk' '6.0' '--family' 'iphone'
[INFO] Showing log output:
[DEBUG] Running: 'tail' '-f' '/var/folders/n6/vlm01gxx2zd0qs35yqh70d8r0000gn/T/tmpL_tpLB'
[DEBUG] 2013-05-11 10:48:21.309 ios-sim-xc4.3[674:507] stderrPath: /var/folders/n6/vlm01gxx2zd0qs35yqh70d8r0000gn/T/tmpL_tpLB
[DEBUG] Unknown or unsupported SDK version: 6.0
[DEBUG] [DEBUG] Simulator SDK Roots:
[DEBUG] [DEBUG] 'Simulator - iOS 6.1' (6.1)
[DEBUG]     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk
```

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: of what? trigger, xcode, ios simulator?

Comment: trigger in particular

Comment: looks like 'Current platform "v1.4" is stable'

Comment: Looks like `v1.4.20 Released: 7th November 2012` was the first with support for 6.1 beta, however `v1.4.44 Released: 9th May 2013` is the newest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just updated the Simulator version in my local config to 6.1 and it worked

Comment: If you want to support and use other iOS simulator versions, go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads

Answer (score 0):

Set the correct iOS Simulator SDK in your app's `local_config.json` file:

`forge-workpsace` > `apps` > `YOUR_APP` > `local_config.json`

```
"ios": {
    "simulatorsdk": "7.0", 
    "simulatorfamily": "iphone", 
    "profiles": {
        "DEFAULT": {}
    }
},
```